# Postgres: composite unique contraint is not used when querying against first column in constraint

Tags: postgresql

Using postgres 14.7

Previously I was under the impression that if a table has a composite unique constraint, then there's no need to put an index on the first column in the constraint. From the docs:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-unique.html

`PostgreSQL automatically creates a unique index when a unique constraint or primary key is defined for a table. The index covers the columns that make up the primary key or unique constraint **(a multicolumn index, if appropriate)**, and is the mechanism that enforces the constraint.`

But based on a simple test with a composite unique constraint including a foreign key, it seems like the unique constraint is actually not used at all when doing a lookup with just the first field. It's only when a condition (or an ordering) with the second field that the unique key is used.

Even if I create the index before inserting all the data, rather than creating it after like below, having an index on the single column is still lower cost and faster than otherwise.

Is there some reason this use case doesn't line up with what the docs say?

1. Create FK table

   `CREATE TABLE uniques_test_alt (id SERIAL CONSTRAINT uniques_alt_pk PRIMARY KEY);`
2. Fill FK table
   `INSERT INTO uniques_test_alt (id) VALUES (1);`
   `INSERT INTO uniques_test_alt (id) VALUES (2);`
3. Create main test table

   `CREATE TABLE uniques_test (`
   `id SERIAL CONSTRAINT uniques_pk PRIMARY KEY,`
   `alt_id INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT uniques_alt_id_fk REFERENCES uniques_test_alt ON DELETE CASCADE,`
   `some_txt varchar(255),`
   `created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,`
   `CONSTRAINT uniques_test_unique UNIQUE (alt_id, some_txt));`
4. Generate a mil records in test table pointing to FK table

   `INSERT INTO uniques_test(alt_id, some_txt, created) SELECT 1, concat('https://', x.id), NOW() FROM generate_series(1,1000000) AS x(id);`

   `INSERT INTO uniques_test(alt_id, some_txt, created) SELECT 2, concat('https://', x.id), NOW() FROM generate_series(1,1000000) AS x(id);`
5. Observe that the first field of unique key is not used for lookup in table with 2mil records

   `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM uniques_test WHERE alt_id = 2;`

   Seq Scan on uniques_test  (cost=0.00..39706.00 rows=1002200 width=30) (actual time=54.192..104.769 rows=1000000 loops=1)
   Filter: (alt_id = 2)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1000000
   Planning Time: 0.221 ms
   Execution Time: 120.997 ms
6. Create an index for the FK

   `CREATE INDEX "uniques_test_alt_idx" ON uniques_test (alt_id);`
7. Observe improvement

   `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM uniques_test WHERE alt_id = 2;`

   Index Scan using uniques_test_alt_idx on uniques_test  (cost=0.43..28311.93 rows=1002200 width=30) (actual time=0.027..73.361 rows=1000000 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (alt_id = 2)
   Planning Time: 0.244 ms
   Execution Time: 91.634 ms

Comment: a difference of 30 milliseconds for a million records is not convincing. That could be explained by caching on OS level. Use `explain(analyze,  verbose, buffers, settings)` for some additional details. An index scan has to read both the index and the table, while a sequential read only reads the table. When 50% of your table is needed, an index scan can actually be slower.

Comment: If all of my tables will have fewer than a million records, does that mean that I am better off creating the index alongside an existing unique constraint? I was mostly looking for a simple test that could exhibit that an index is not needed when there's a unique constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it without the additional index and got this on Postgres 14.7:

```
 Index Scan using uniques_test_unique on uniques_test  (cost=0.43..6.20 rows=1 width=30) (actual time=0.007.
.244.810 rows=1000000 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (alt_id = 2)
 Planning Time: 0.141 ms
 Execution Time: 271.509 ms
```

Try running an ANALYZE when full of data to update the planning costs.

Given the time it took to do the inserts (not long) it may be that there's not enough data to always convince the planner to use an index.